# Chart.js and async data loading in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I am trying to create a chart.js line chart that shows public traffic ticket data. I have a component that calls a helper datareader js function to load the data. The issue I am facing that I am not doing the async part correctly, and the data loads after the chart is rendered.

Here is the component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
} from 'chart.js';
import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import faker from 'faker';
import {GetParkingTicketTimes} from  '../helper/DataReader.js'


ChartJS.register(
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend
);

export const options = {
  responsive: true,
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      position: 'top' 
    },
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Chart.js Line Chart',
    },
  },
};

const labels = ['00:00', '01:00', '02:00', '03:00', '04:00', '05:00', '06:00', '07:00', '08:00', '09:00', '10:00', '11:00', '12:00', '13:00', '14:00', '15:00', '16:00', '17:00', '18:00', '19:00', '20:00', '21:00', '22:00', '23:00'];

export const data = {
  labels,
  datasets: [
    {
      label: '2016',
      data: labels.map(() => faker.datatype.number({ min: -1000, max: 1000 })),
      borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)',
    },
    {
      label: 'Dataset 2',
      data: labels.map(() => faker.datatype.number({ min: -1000, max: 1000 })),
      borderColor: 'rgb(53, 162, 235)',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(53, 162, 235, 0.5)',
    },
  ],
};

export function TimeOfDayTickets() {
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const data = await GetParkingTicketTimes('2017');
      console.log(data);
      setChartData({
        labels: labels,
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "Traffic Tickets",
            data: data, 
            borderColor: 'rgb(53, 162, 235)',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(53, 162, 235, 0.5)',     
          }
        ]
      });
    }
    fetchData()
  }, []);
  
  const [chartData, setChartData] = useState({})

  return <Line options={options} data={chartData} />;
}

export default TimeOfDayTickets
```

Here is the helper function

```
import { usePapaParse } from "react-papaparse";
import parkingTickets2017 from "../data/Parking_Tickets_2017.csv";

function getDataSetByYear(year) {
  switch (year) {
    case "2017":
      return parkingTickets2017;
    default: 
    }
}

export async function GetParkingTicketTimes(year) {
  let countByHour = {};

  const papaConfig = {
    header: true,
    complete: (results, file) => {
      console.log("Parsing complete:", results, file);
      // Getting just the times
      let times = results.data.map((a) => a.ISSUETIME);
      // Go through each time and put them in appropriate hour bucket
      for (let i = 0; i < times.length; i++) {
        if (times[i]) {
          let h = times[i].substring(0, 2);
          if (!countByHour[h]) {
            countByHour[h] = 0;
          }
          countByHour[h]++;
        }
      }
      return countByHour;
    },
    download: true,
    error: (error, file) => {
      console.log("Error while parsing:", error, file);
    },
  };

  const { readString } = usePapaParse();
  await readString(getDataSetByYear(year), papaConfig);
}
```

The return countByHour is returned too late. What is the right way to do this?

Comment: You're calling `await GetParkingTicketTimes('2017')` but `GetParkingTicketTimes` is returning the default Promise (since you aren't returning one). Which means the function call will resolve immediately, before the async code inside the function finishes. To fix this, you probably only need to `return readString(getDataSetByYear(year), papaConfig);`

Comment: That doesn't seem to do it. return countByHour is still called after the fact.

Comment: Seems like you need to introduce the loading state and wait for fetch to be done and then render the component.

Comment: @Sodhisaab how exactly do I do that?

Comment: could you please create codesandbox for it. it would be easy to implement there